# DocumentDB Trace listener

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, tracelistener

I'm trying register DocumentDB tracing with an existing listener. The code snippet below properly traces a single message to my expected listener but not the actual traces generated by the DocumentDB C# client. Am I missing something?

Snippet from Global.asax:

```
private static TraceSource DocDBSource;
private static TraceListener ExistingListener = new .....;

public void RegisterDocDBListener() {
    DocDBSource = new TraceSource("DocDBTrace");
    DocDBSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Information;
    DocDBSource.Listeners.Add(ExistingListener);
    DocDBSource.TraceInformation("DocDB tracing initialized");
}
```

Comment: I'd need to see what sort of listener is the new ....  Or if you got things mixed, if you are also doing the same thing in App.Config or Web.Config. This shows ConsoleTraceListener for example system.diagnostics

Comment: Sorry, the link didn't paste- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further support?

Answer (score 4):

According to your description, I have checked the `DefaultTrace` from DocumentDB client library for .NET as follows:

[image]

For Client-side Logging with the .NET DocumentDB Client Library, you could configure the `system.diagnostics` configuration as follows to collect and persist documentdb log messages to a text file as follows:

```html
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="DocDBTrace">
      <listeners>
        <!--ConsoleTraceListener-->
        <add name="configConsoleListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
        <!--TextWriterTraceListener-->
        <add name="myListener"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <switches>
    <add name="ClientSwitch" value="Warning"/>
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

**Note:** The default Log Level is Information, you could change the `ClientSwitch` to your expected Log Level (Off, Error, Information, Verbose).

**Result**

- Console Application

[image]

- Web Application

[image]